# Julia plot not output in REPL

Tags: julia

I am trying to follow this amazing tutorial here https://mitmath.github.io/18S096SciML/lecture2/ml . The plot function doesn't output anything.

I am expecting a nice picture as shown in the tutorial.

```
julia> sol = solve(prob)
retcode: Success
Interpolation: Automatic order switching interpolation
t: 18-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
  0.12042171636511094
  0.3940250318974269
  0.7431714989426645
  1.1908117700408676
  1.6696453651245915
  2.1515965996714526
  2.841074498400511
  3.3224870404127125
  4.205901310769404
  4.85103235599461
  5.75220957647161
  6.51936634259325
  7.376557754870432
  8.05693616586297
  8.76695241877244
  9.654689717516431
 10.0
u: 18-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0619035131908614, 1.0037013967424924]
 [1.211227612874576, 1.0417278157780603]
 [1.395948006879763, 1.1591295610585277]
 [1.5360673274292003, 1.437108787544826]
 [1.4400650630904333, 1.8360964058306817]
 [1.132734306667471, 2.1167012173641306]
 [0.7457939523836609, 2.0023312477877138]
 [0.6262131837008384, 1.7134217487709205]
 [0.6539339775621856, 1.2219165477768923]
 [0.8398246099571697, 1.0301746525015527]
 [1.2940466137751767, 1.0821741693585762]
 [1.5386169493414976, 1.5339695110793223]
 [1.1233423139235204, 2.1208244641349996]
 [0.744012848233364, 2.000404253981646]
 [0.60607597743536, 1.5662699127838058]
 [0.7062343579716562, 1.1320585960753804]
 [0.8157332023838473, 1.0411904685890365]

julia> plot(sol)
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows in a different window.
[image]

Comment: Does this resolve your issue then? Basically, it was rendering—just not where you were expecting it? Or are you still having issues?

Comment: How to output that in REPL?